# AS3 | Variable with hexColor

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

My code:

```
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;

var brushColor:Number;

cp_color.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor);

function changeColor(e:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    brushColor = '0x' + e.target.hexValue;
    updateBrush();
}

function updateBrush():void {
    myDrawingMarker.graphics.lineStyle(brushSize, brushColor, brushAlpha);
}
```

My goal is to make brushColor = "0xffffff", where ffffff is code choose from Color Picker. What type must be variable?

Comment: You want int or uint and remember it is base 16 var decimal:int = parseInt("FFFFFF",16); // output : 16777215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lineStyle` method expects a parameter of type `uint` (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29)). The `color` property of the `ColorPickerEvent` contains the current color of the color picker as a uint (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/events/ColorPickerEvent.html)).

I think if you update your code as follows it should work.

```
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;

var brushColor:uint; // lineStyle method expects parameter of type uint

cp_color.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor);

function changeColor(e:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    brushColor = e.color; // event's color property is of the correct type
    updateBrush();
}

function updateBrush():void {
    myDrawingMarker.graphics.lineStyle(brushSize, brushColor, brushAlpha);
}
```

Comment: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type uint.

Comment: Sorry - sloppy on my part. See updated answer (removed the '0'+ from the assignment to brushColor)